# Is it possible to access substructs based on location

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a struct like so:

```
master = struct('a',struct(),'b',struct())
```

in R this would be a list of vectors and I could access the first or second element using master[1] or master[2]. Is it possible to do this in Matlab?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, got a little cocky with my coding... Fixed now, just creates two empty substructs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.

You could use [dynamic field references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) with the [`fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) of your structure:

```
master = struct('a',struct('hi', 1),'b',struct('hi', 2));
myfields = fieldnames(master); % Need temporary variable

master.(myfields{1})
```

Which returns:

```
ans = 

    hi: 1
```

You can also create an array of structs:

```
master(1) = struct('a', 1, 'b', 2);
master(2) = struct('a', 3, 'b', 4);
```

Which you could index (sorta) similarly to R:

```
>> [master(1).a master(2).b]

ans =

     1     4
>> [master(:).a]

ans =

     1     3
```